# Return status from webpurify javascript check method to main program

Tags: javascript, api

I just stuck in this code.

I'm using webpurify(http://webpurify.com/) javascript api for profanity checking. Javascript api link is here : http://webpurify.com/documentation/samples/javascript.php

I've made this function..

```
function check()
{
    $.webpurify.check( $("#check").val(), function(isProfane){
        return isProfane;
    });    
}
```

What this function will do.. Whatever the profanity checking status(isProfane value) generate, function should return that value.  But, here it is returning 'undefined'.

I don't know what's wrong is going on with this.

Answer (score 0):

Two guesses, one from experience with other jQuery functions and the other from basic knowledge.

I think what happens inside of the function function(isProfane) stays inside of the function function(isProfane), so that when you return it from function(isProfane) then basically nothing happens.

The other thing is, what if isProfane is never given a value? What is isProfane? is it suppose to be the value of #check ? At least it can't be it since you're not assigning it. A variable is undefined if it's value is never given.

You should take a closer look at the documentation of the .check function and how jQuery functions work with assigning variables and returning.

If you want check() to return isProfane then you'd have to do it after the .check function, for the sakes of similar reasons as I mentioned first.